# Failing to install Aptana

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Aptana on Ubuntu : I extracted the files from the zip folder, I moved the aptana soft to a directory I created. I launched Aptana from there, everything was right till I wanted to create a project, I have this error message :

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handlesNative code library failed to load. (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/mbenchoufi/aptana/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.1345233987/os/linux/x86/libcefjni.so: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Did I miss to install some packages ?
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a package. Try installing it via:
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`